# Android textview show link and no underlined link web

Tags: android, android-webview, textview

i have some error about textview show link web.i want to no underlined link web.i have reading some example, but it have not resolution.thanks
It is code :

```
 TextView txWebview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo_question);
        txWebview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txWebview);
        txWebview.setText(
                                 Html.fromHtml("http://www.google.com"));
        stripUnderlines(txWebview);

    }
    public class URLSpanNoUnderline extends URLSpan {
        public URLSpanNoUnderline(String url) {
            super(url);
        }
        @Override public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    }
    private void stripUnderlines(TextView textView) {
        Spannable s = new SpannableString(textView.getText());
        URLSpan[] spans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), URLSpan.class);
        for (URLSpan span: spans) {
            int start = s.getSpanStart(span);
            int end = s.getSpanEnd(span);
            s.removeSpan(span);
            span = new URLSpanNoUnderline(span.getURL());
            s.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);
        }
        textView.setText(s);
    }
```

and xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".DemoQuestionActivity">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txWebview"
      android:autoLink="web"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but result no correct:[image]

Comment: What is incorrect? As I see, the web link is underlined - as you wish.

Comment: sory. i miss.no underlined.

Comment: Is it clickable ? Is it working on click event?

Comment: yes.but important is hide underline link

Answer (score 0):

Method `stripUnderlines` uses for remove the underline from HyperLink.

```
testTV.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"www.google.com\">google</a>"));
stripUnderlines(testTV);
```

It works like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you has omit the following code before stripUnderlines(txWebview):

```
txWebview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and you can't setMovementMethod after stripUnderlines().

I has tried it.